# Spring Rest Controller POST request doesn't work

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/query")
public class QueryController {

    @Autowired
    private QueryService queryService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/select", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody QueryResultDTO executeQuery(@RequestBody QueryDTO queryDTO) {
        try {
            QueryResultDTO queryResultDTO = queryService.executeQuery("select * from employees");
            queryResultDTO.setSuccessful(true);
            return queryResultDTO;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            QueryResultDTO queryResultDTO = new QueryResultDTO();
            queryResultDTO.setSuccessful(false);
            queryResultDTO.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
            return queryResultDTO;
        }
    }
}
```

and I try to send POST request from AngularJS controller:

```
app.controller("AppCtrl",function($scope,$http) {
    var app = this;

    $scope.execute= function () {
        $http({
            url: '../query/select',
            method: "POST",
            data: { 'message' : $scope.queryText }
        })
            .then(function(response) {
                    $scope.queryResult = response.data;
                    console.log($scope.queryResult);
                    console.log($scope.queryText)
                },
                function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
    }

});
```

but It doesn't work. My `executeQuery` function in Spring Controller isn't even called.

But when I change RequestMethod to GET it works correctly.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/query")
public class QueryController {

    @Autowired
    private QueryService queryService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/select", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody QueryResultDTO executeQuery() {
        try {
            QueryResultDTO queryResultDTO = queryService.executeQuery("INSERT INTO employee VALUES (7,'dupa')");
            queryResultDTO.setSuccessful(true);
            return queryResultDTO;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            QueryResultDTO queryResultDTO = new QueryResultDTO();
            queryResultDTO.setSuccessful(false);
            queryResultDTO.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
            return queryResultDTO;
        }
    }
}
```

and in Angular controller:

```
app.controller("AppCtrl",function($scope,$http) {
    var app = this;

    $scope.execute= function () {
        $http({
            url: '../query/select',
            method: "GET",
            data: { 'message' : $scope.queryText }
        })
            .then(function(response) {
                    $scope.queryResult = response.data;
                    console.log($scope.queryResult);
                    console.log($scope.queryText)
                },
                function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
    }

});
```

My main problem is that I'd like to send some data to my Spring controller and then send `JSON` in response to my Angular controller. Whith `GET` method response works perfectly, but when I use `POST` the controller method isn't even called.

Edit:

My `QueryDTO` class is simple:

```
public class QueryDTO {

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

And some logs with `DEBUG` level:

```
2016-06-06 09:28:23.697 DEBUG 7504 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-06-06 09:28:23.698 DEBUG 7504 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

Comment: What are the required attributes for QueryDTO? Please post its code. Have you tried making explicit the response? Defining [the produces param](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/17053353/).

Comment: Finally, you can also try changing the firm adding the [request param](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/17053491/).

Comment: How is your QueryDTO look like? Did you check in the logs if Spring message converter is converting JSON into QueryDTO.

Comment: I've updated my post with QueryDTO code and some logs.

Comment: Can you set org.springframework.web to DEBUG in your log config and paste the trace?

Comment: You don't need `@ResponseBody` when you have `@RestController`. That's the main point of using it. What's the response when you POST?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` in your method.

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "/userlogincheck", method = RequestMethod.POST,   consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody void userLoginCheck(@RequestBody UserImpl user, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws JSONException, IOException {
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
        String email=user.getEmail();
        Long userId=user.getId();
        User loginData = accountService.userLoginCheck(email,userId);
        if(loginData==null)
        {
            json.put("status", "FAILURE");
            json.put("message", "user does not exist");
            json.put("nextPage", "signIn");
        }
        else
        {
            json.put("status", "SUCCESS");
            json.put("nextPage", updateState);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }
    response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    logger.info("response======" + json.toString());
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write(json.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it by adding CSRF token to my request (this is only an issue if you are using the WebSecurity). https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html

This link describe the following steps:

1) Add the token to your header, with thymeleaf you do as follows (I think you can fetch the token from cookie as well):

```
<head>
   <meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
.....
</head>
```

2) Change your request to include the CSRF token as follows (I am not familiar with angular but I guess you can set the header the same way as I did with Jquery):

```
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
  $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: url,
          data: JSON.stringify(newTodo),
          headers: {
             'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
          },
          contentType: 'application/json',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(){
            alert('callback ');
         }
      });
```